# Remove a field of my json in a specific case

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an ExpressJS controller that list all my users

**userCtrl.get** :

```
get(req, res, next) {
  var func = function(err, data) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.json(data);
  };

  if (req.params[this.idName])
    this._getById(req.params[this.idName], func);
  else
    this._getAll(func);
  }

  _getById(id, fn) {
    this.ObjectClass.findById(id, fn);
  }
  _getAll(fn) {
    this.ObjectClass.findAll(fn);
  }
```

I'd like to call it from another road, in such a way that **res.json()** will filter a field of this json
Something like :

```
router.get ('/services/:serviceKey/authBridge/users', function(req, res, next) {
  function anonJs(x) {
    x.forEach(s => s.credential = null);
    res.json(x);
  }
  res.json = anonJs;
  userCtrl.get(req, res, next);
});
```

The problem is, with this last piece of code I end up with a recursion as I call `res.json` that is now defined as `anonJS`

Answer (score 0):

You must store the reference to the old function before replacing it.

```
router.get ('/services/:serviceKey/authBridge/users', function(req, res, next) {
  var json = res.json;
  res.json = function(x) {
    x.forEach(s => s.credential = null);
    json(x);
  }

  userCtrl.get(req, res, next);
});
```